# Como enviar várias pastas usando SSH (SCP)

Tags: bash, ssh

Tenho um arquivo "deploy.sh" que tem o seguinte comando:

```
scp -r ./public_html usuario-ssh@dominio-para-envio-ssh.com -p 9922
```

Porém o comando fica dando erro:

> No such file or directory

Mas a pasta `public_html` está no mesmo diretório do arquivo `deploy.sh`.

- Por que ele diz que o arquivo não foi encontrado?
- Como faço para mandar múltiplas pastas (public_html, app, vendor, etc...) de uma única vez?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela definição do SCP, você precisa especificar o caminho de origem (OK) e o caminho de destino (NÃO OK). Vide [man page scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

```
scp ... [user@]host1:]file1 ... [user@]host2:]file2
```

Os outros parâmetros que você especificou estão corretos:

- **-r** para recursivo. Esse você usar para enviar vários arquivos dentro do caminho especificado ("de uma vez"), desde que todos estejam dentro do diretório **./public_html** (no seu exemplo). Para enviar arquivos individualmente, precisa de um shell script que liste os arquivos e execute o envio um a um (algo mesclando o *find* com o *xargs*).
- **-p** para porta.

Faltou mesmo especificar o caminho do destino. Como ficaria o comando: (note o **:/var/www/**):

```
scp -p 9922 -r ./public_html usuario-ssh@dominio-para-envio-ssh.com:/var/www/
```

Outro detalhe *importantíssimo* é a permissão. O usuário **usuario-ssh** deve ter permissão de escrita no diretório **/var/www/**.

<sub>Obs.: A porta não pode ficar no final do comando, senão é confundida com o diretório de destino.</sub>

Comment: Coloquei o caminho conforme o servidor `:/home/meusite.com/public/` mesmo assim não deu. Continua o mesmo erro "No such file or directory", removi a porta e ele não conseguiu conectar.

Comment: Consegui resolver o erro passando o parâmetro da porta pro início do comando: `scp -p 9922 [user@]host1:]file1 ... [user@]host2:]file2`